# How do I redirect to the current page in php?

Tags: php, redirect, header

How do I use the header redirect to make it redirect to the current page?

**EDIT:** I am trying to make it reload the currently shown page in the browser.

Comment: ? :-/  Can you tell us what your understanding of the word "redirect" is?

Comment: I think that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Are you asking to redirect or refresh (as in repeating GET and POST data)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> EDIT: I am trying to make it reload
>   the currently shown page in the
>   browser.

PHP by itself can't force a page refresh. You'll need to use javascript:

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.location.reload(true)" value="Reload It" />
```

The `.reload(true)` bit instructs the browser to do a hard refresh (i.e., fetch a new copy of the web page from the server).

Comment: you can of course do this without needing the browser by adding it to the (e.g.) onLoad event of an element

Answer (score 3):

```
header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Comment: I'd be a little wary -- might it be possible for an attacker to craft a value of the `Host` header, or a URI that might do something a little unexpected when shoved directly into a `Location` header?  Might be a good idea to at least `filter_var()`...

Comment: @Frank good thinking, but according to the feedback to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209894/sanitation-for-url-used-in-header-location seemingly not an issue.

Comment: @Frank Farmer: i can't imagine any really evil data here.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to give us a better understanding of the question.  But from what I can tell, you are looking for this:

```
 header("Location: ".$url);
 exit(1); // Needed!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following at the very beginning of mypage.php:

```
header('Location: /mypage.php');
```

Some info from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'mypage.php';
header('Location: ' . $url);
die('<a href="' . $url . '">Click Here</a> if you are not redirected.');
```

Redirects to *mypage.php*. If that fails, the user is given a message and link to the redirected page.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in HTML with no PHP at all... Simple, but not always suited to your needs (Meta will work EVERY time the page loads)

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;url=http://www.yoursite.com/yourpage.htm" />
```

Where:

1. content = seconds to redirect
2. url = the page you want to redirect to.

Answer (score 0):

If you are rewriting your url you can use `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']` to get the current page.